# How to user Powershell 'invoke-expression' to run an executable as a different user

Tags: windows, powershell, executable

I have a c++ service application that launches a Powershell script (powershell.exe script.ps1).  In the script an executable is run but needs to be run with different user credentials.  Is there a way to do this in Powershell with the invoke-expression cmdlet or some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Start-Process` e.g.:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -arg "/k whoami.exe" -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Of course, for your script you will need to create a credential programmatically rather then using the `Get-Credential` which prompts for username/password.